# How to create 3D Surface Plots with Python using Excel Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data avaialable, which I need to represent in 3D Plot.

[Random Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pdb6.png)

Unfortunately, all the tutorials I found online defined X and Y and used a function to define Z. In my case, I need to define all 3 and then generate a plot.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

I tried creating rows for X,Y,Z and followed an example and was able to generate something, but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a scatter plot in 3D:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create sample data
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.random.rand(10)

# Create 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=z, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

---

For a surface plot, you would need two 1D arrays for the X and Y coordinates and a 2D array for the Z values. You can create a mesh using `np.meshgrid()` from the X and Y arrays, and then use the resulting X, Y, and Z arrays to create a surface plot using plot_surface() function in mpl_toolkits.mplot3d. I created a simple example below, so you can look at the size and what the data look like before a surface plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create data
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y)

# create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm')

# add a color bar
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```